# pyparsing: Unable to get results from ParseResults object

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

```py
>>> from pyparsing import Word, alphanums, OneOrMore, Optional, Suppress

>>> var = Word(alphanums)
>>> reg = OneOrMore(var('predictors') + Optional(Suppress('+'))) + '~' + OneOrMore(var('covariates') + Optional(Suppress('+')))

>>> string = 'y1 ~ f1 + f2 + f3'
>>> reg.parseString(string)
(['y1', '~', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'], {'predictors': ['y1'], 'covariates': ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']})
```

It is able to parse things correctly but I am unable to get all the values of `predictors` and `covariates`. It only seems to store the last value:

```py
>>> results = reg.parseString(string)
>>> results.covariates
'f3'
>>> results['covariates']
'f3'
```

I would like to get all the values in `predictors` and `covariates` as lists . Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Reopened - the proposed duplicate, while including information that helps answer this question, buries the actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results names by default use similar logic as Python dicts: if there are multiple values assigned for the same key, only the last assigned value is kept.

However, this behavior can be overridden, depending how the parser defines the results names.

If using the full `expr.setResultsName("XYZ")` form, add `listAllMatches=True` argument. This tells pyparsing to keep a list of all parsed values and return them as a list.

If using the short-cut `expr("XYZ")` form, add a `'*'` to the end of the name: `expr("XYZ*")`. This is equivalent to setting `listAllMatches` to True.

The trailing `'*'` is there in `setResultsName` for those cases where you use the short form of `setResultsName`: `expr("name*")` vs `expr.setResultsName("name", listAllMatches=True)`. If you prefer calling `setResultsName`, then do not use the `'*'` notation, but instead pass the `listAllMatches` argument.